# Should a class kill the application?

Tags: php, oop

Consider a web application that is made up of several classes. Each class has its own client - program/script that creates an object of the class.
The question is this, when a client creates an object or uses a method of a class/object, and something goes wrong in the class, should:

- class terminate the application
- class return a false and it's up to client to take proper action
- throw and exception

Which one of these is considered best practice?

Comment: personally i would go for the second option, you set up your own error tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw an exception. It's the cleanest way to handle the abnormal situations.

Never terminate the application from inside a function of a method. They should not know about the context where they run. Throw an exception (or return `FALSE`/`NULL`/empty string/whatever is most appropriate for your application) and let the higher level code (the caller) decide how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Depends why it failed i guess. without knowing what the situation is, i would say to display a 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on a size and complexity of your code base, you could use any of those methods depending on a case, but the most professional one to use would be `class return a false and it's up to client to take proper action`.

With your own `debug` class it could decide what to do next, i.e. `destruct` class instances, close file handles, flush buffer, like I said depends on your code base. It's a good habit to handle errors with a custom `error/debug class`.

Hope that helps you.